Hook Before Each BDD Step Action BDD Patrol Tester
I have updated my build.yaml file and my .dart test files are all successfully providing the beforeAll etc hooks.
   setUpAll(() async {
    await Hooks.beforeAll();

  });
  tearDownAll(() async {
    await Hooks.afterAll();
  });

However, is there a way to provide a hook in between each step action:
await iAmOnTheCartScreen(tester);
   <hook>
 await iScanTheFirstProduct(tester);
   <hook>
 await theProductIsAddedToTheCart(tester);

